# JQuery: How can I select a single li when hovering?

Tags: jquery

So I'm in a situation where I have a gallery made out of ul li elements, and I want to make it so that when I hover over an li jQuery selects only that li and fades in a div within the li itself. I know I can get it done with ID tags, but by doing so I'll have to write code for each. I wanted to know if there is a way to select only the li you are currently hovering over, and then how to select the div within it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(function(){
    $("ul.gallery li div").hide();//starting state

     $("ul.gallery li").hover(function(){
        $('ul.gallery li > div').stop().fadeTo("200", 1.0);//hover state
     },function(){
     $('ul.gallery li > div').stop().fadeTo("200", 0.0);//mouse off state
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `this` keyword inside your hover event handler to get the specific element. ie `$("div", this).stop()....`

edit: actually `$(this).children("div")...` is faster.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out the difference between `this` and `$(this)`, but +1 for already answering the question :)

Comment: I don't know wether children() is faster then your way, but it's much easier to read (and in this example speed doesn't matter that much)

Comment: `$("div", this)` uses `$.find()` internally; which, is slower than `$.children()`, as children only traverses the immediate children whereas `$.find()` traverse the entire dom node.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $("ul.gallery li div").hide();//starting state

    $("ul.gallery li").hover(function(){
        $(this).children('div').stop().fadeTo("200", 1.0);//hover state
    },function(){
        $(this).children('div').stop().fadeTo("200", 0.0);//mouse off state
    });
});
```

`this` refers to the current DOM context (the `li`, because the selector of the hover function is `ul.gallery li`), to get a jQuery object, you have to use `$(this)`. The [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method gives all children in this element filtered by a selector.

See the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/srakesh/hmD3V/

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast! I never knew that by adding the children  method with (this) it would only select the current li's div. Awesome! Thanks again!